# Using spring service inside of ejb 3.1 stateless timer

Tags: java, spring, ejb, ejb-3.1, stripes

I know that the general consensus is to use one or the other, but we have a specific task where we would like to use our spring services from within a stateless ejb timer.

Is there a standard way of getting a spring service from outside the normal flow of my web app? (Note I'm using the stripes framework and it has built in spring support and I'm using this built in support to access my spring services normally)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Spring manual you can configure an [EJB 3 injection interceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/ejb.html#ejb-implementation-ejb3) that will take care of injecting @Autowired springbeans into your EJB Session Beans.